# Glob import of image urls in SvelteKit

Tags: sveltekit

I am trying to import all urls for images in a directory in a wildcard fashion, with two possible extensions:

```js
import urls from "../static/images/**/*.{png,svg}";
```

Currently there are three files in this directory, importing them individually works fine. When I use this syntax, the files are not found:

> Failed to resolve import "../static/images/**/*.{png,svg}" from
> "src/routes/index.svelte". Does the file exist?

I had heard that it was possible to do this out of the box in SvelteKit, do I need to enable or define the pattern of import in jsconfig.json file in order to achieve this functionality, or install a dependency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed by changing import to use meta.glob:

```js
const urls = import.meta.glob("../static/images/**/*.{png,svg}");
```

Comment: The reason for it is probably because [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) are performed by the shell (bash, in this case) and isn't available on ESM imports by default. Passing the path through the `import.meta.glob` achieves the same result

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I additionally had to set [the eager option](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) to `true` to load all components in a certain folder:

```js
const components = import.meta.glob('./../lib/test/**.svelte', { eager: true });
```

Without this option, I always received an empty object.

Answer (score 3):

> I know this question is already solved and old, But I want to add more info (for what worked for me, so if someone in the future will have my same bug, can easily solve it using also mine)

using the @Daniel Veihelmann answer solved my issue (for svelte components)

basically, I have to set `{ eager: true }` or it will give you `undefined`

and I used this code:

```html
<script>
  const modules = import.meta.glob("./Pages/*.svelte", { eager: true });
  const pages = Object.keys(modules).map((key) => modules[key].default);
</script>

{#each pages as page}
  <svelte:component this={page} />
{/each}
```

now I dynamically rendered all the pages from a folder. (you can use the same approach for images and render them using each block if you want)

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted to do. How do I add the correct type annotations for typescript? It can't infer the type of modules[key] and says Object is of type 'unknown'