# How to process groups of images in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

I've learned you can use [vite's import.meta.glob function to do glob imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68060723/glob-import-of-image-urls-in-sveltekit). Is there any way to do compile-time image processing, like with vite-imagetools, on images imported this way? For example:

```
import.meta.glob("./*.{jpg,png}?w=500;800&webp&source");
```

Or even after I've imported the glob so that I could convert the same glob to AVIF as well if I wanted to?

If not, is there another way to batch process a group of images without having to explicitly import each specific image in an import statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For glob imports you have to add query parameters separately like this:

```js
import.meta.glob("./*.{jpg,png}", { query: 'w=500;800&webp&source' });
```